# How to download HTML element, which shows upon inspection, but not after displaying whole page source?

Tags: html, web-scraping

I am currently learning how to scrape and I bumped into a problem. On sensortower.com, there's a functionality that allows to display a rank of an app. For example, here's a URL for Snapchat:

https://sensortower.com/android/US/snap-inc/app/snapchat/com.snapchat.android/category-rankings?search=&start_date=2019-06-30&end_date=2019-09-27&countries=US&chart_type=free&device=android&selected_tab=charts&date=2019-09-27&category=all&summary_chart_type=topselling_free

At the bottom of the above website, you can see a table with 'Today's Rank' and corresponding value of '8'. When I click 'inspect' on the '8' I get the following part of the site:

```
<td data-bind="text: $data.rank">8</td>
```

However, when I click 'View page source', this particular snippet or anything similar is nowehre to be seen. Please advise how to obtain the downloadable URL where the mentioned value could be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no downloadable URL for web scraping. The webserver sends your browser the html,css and js you see when you click 'View page source' by executing the js the content you see on the website can change. Here all the data most likely gets loaded in afterwards by the js. So if you want to scrape that data either look at how the website loads it in or use some scraping library that can build the whole website for you.

Looking at what URLs the site loads in I found this REST API that has the data you are looking for:

https://sensortower.com/api/android/category/category_history?app_ids[]=com.snapchat.android&os=android&countries[]=US&categories[]=all&chart_type_ids[]=topselling_free&start_date=2019-06-30T00:00:00.000Z&end_date=2019-09-27T00:00:00.000Z&is_hourly=false

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and the API link! Would you kindly explain how did you get the URLs that the site loads, so you could get that particular API?

Comment: @MichalStefaniak Im using chrome and under developer tools there is a network tab. I filtered for "api" and looked at the urls that were loaded in there. Im not sure how to do it with other browsers but im sure others have this functionality as well.
https://i.imgur.com/Yp5KiQY.png

Comment: Thank you a lot, I didn't know you can do that. Very useful!

Comment: response['com.snapchat.android']['US']['all']['topselling_free']['todays_rank']